# How do I get an alert or error message to display in my app if the api is unable to locate the breed name passed in by the user

Tags: javascript, api

```js
function getDogImage(breed) {
  fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${breed}/images/random`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => 
      displayResults(responseJson))
    .catch(error => alert('Something went wrong. Try again later.'));
}

function displayResults(responseJson) {
  console.log(responseJson);
  //replace the existing image with the new one
  $('.results-img').replaceWith(
    `<img src="${responseJson.message}" class="results-img">`
  )
  //display the results section
  $('.results').removeClass('hidden');
}

function watchForm() {
  $('form').submit(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    getDogImage($('#breed').val());
  });
}

$(function() {
  console.log('App loaded! Waiting for submit!');
  watchForm();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Dog API Example</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Dog API: A Simple Example</h1>
           
        <form>
             <label for="breed">Breed</label>
      <input type="search" name="phone" id="breed" placeholder="Enter Breed" title="dog breeds" required/>

          <input type="submit" value="Get a dog pic!">
        </form>
        <section class="results hidden">
          <h2>Look at this dog!</h2>
          <img class="results-img" alt="placeholder">
        </section>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I get an alert or error message to display in my app if the api is unable to locate the breed name passed in by the user. At the moment a broken image link is displayed when passing in a non-valid breed name. Also im new to programming just here trying to learn from experienced developers

Heres a link to my code
https://repl.it/@Mike65/get-fetch-dog-api-example-DOM-3

Comment: img tag has onError event you can tie alert function to it, also "${responseJson.message}" <-- is wrong you need to use this quote ` instead of "

Comment: How do i tie in the alert function?

Comment: Can someone please help me out

Comment: I wrote you short example, you can checkout more info about event handling in JQuery docs

Answer (score 0):

img tag has onerror event, you can call alert function on that event like this

**HTML**

```
<img src=`${response.message}` class='result-img' onerror="myAlert()" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function myAlert() { alert("the image could not load"); }
```

**JQuery**

```
  $('.results-img').replaceWith(
`<img src="${responseJson.message}" class="results-img">`
  ).on("error", function() { alert("the image could not load"); }
```

Comment: im trying to make changes to my js but where would i insert these code snippets in my app? I tried adding it as a new function. please help if you can

Comment: It's been ages I did something with JQuery but I think my edited answer should work for your case.

Comment: Do i create a whole other function or add this code to my existing code the error message displays in the console but it wont display on the front end it just shows a broken img upon entering a invalid breed name

Comment: how do i get the error code to display outside of the console?